# Angular 8 Material table with sorting works fine locally but not on Stackblitz / different @ViewChild timing?

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-table

For demonstration purpose I created a rich featured Angular 8 Material table demo, that runs fine locally, but not on Stackblitz.

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/github/KarlDegen/angular-table-inline-editing-with-drag-and-drop)

The demo shows in one single table

- inline editing,
- drag and drop,
- pagination, (<- has initialization problem on Stackblitz)
- sorting and (<- has problem on Stackblitz)
- add/remove data.

As far as I can interpret the console, the error araises from the fact, that the component properties holding the sort (this._sort) and pagination (this._pagination) should be set by @ViewChild() but are still undefined even in ngAfterViewInit(){}.

Stackblitz Console

- Error: this._sort is undefined
- Error: this._paginator is undefined

Question: any idea why it works fine locally, but not on Stackblitz. Did I do a mistake and having it run locally is just by chance?

Comment: Stackblitz link is broken

Comment: Thanks, @KurtHamilton, a little 'p' was missing at the end. Now the link worls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using direct imports in your Stackblitz seems to solve your errors:

```
import { MatSortModule } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatPaginatorModule} from '@angular/material/paginator';
```

Check the adapted [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-w2lgbu?file=src/app/shared/material.module.ts).

Comment: Indeed, this fixed the problem. Thanx a lot!